# Launching speech preferences pane on macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, macos-sierra

Is it possible to launch preferences pane with Accessibility/Speech open on macOS Sierra? For accessibility I am aware you can do that with `x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.universalaccess`. I am also aware that most tabs in Accessiblity pane can be opened when launched, but there is no document for whether it is possible for Speech tab on Sierra. This is the most comprehensive link I have found thus far: https://macosxautomation.com/system-prefs-links.html, but it predates Sierra and speech belonged to different pane then, so it is listed but that link isn't useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.universalaccess?TextToSpeech`

The anchors for the pane can be retrieved by opening it and then querying the app with applescript:

```
tell application "System Preferences" to get anchors of current pane
```

Which returns:

```
"Keyboard"
"Dwell"
"Captioning"
"Seeing_VoiceOver"
"SpeakableItems"
"TextToSpeech"
"Hearing"
"Switch"
"General"
"Media_Descriptions"
"Mouse"
"Seeing_Display"
"Seeing_Zoom"
```

Answer (score 0):

https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25806?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US, with title

> macOS Sierra: Speech pane of Accessibility System Preferences

indicates that the speech pane is still there.

> Use the Speech pane of Accessibility System Preferences to customize the system voice, be notified when an alert or app needs your attention, and set a shortcut to speak selected text.
>
> To open this pane, choose Apple menu > System Preferences, click Accessibility, then click Speech.

Comment: It wasn't there in the previous versions, check the link above. It was nested among the top level preferences.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get that.  So this is of no use to you?

Comment: Unfortunately, not. The other answer here is correct and it has resolved the problem.